Control access scopes in google chat bot using apps script
I have made a google chat app using apps script. While deployed the app I have made the script running as me itself. But on configuration by users, it is asking for edit, read access to the user's spreadsheet
I don't want to ask the user permission for their spreadsheet datas, instead just this single spreadsheet access is needed

There is no way to limit authorization scopes to access a single spreadsheet for a chatbot.
The closest to this is to add /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */, but this only works for bounded scripts.
Your best option might be to use UrlFetchApp with authorization credentials that you could store in your project, assuming you keep it private.
